# real time ETW consumer of file events EDD08927-9CC4-4E65-B970-C2560FB5C289 in VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, etw

I am trying to create a REAL TIME ETW consumer in VC++ . My objective is to get the file names which are accessed. I am using the GUID. Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File            {EDD08927-9CC4-4E65-B970-C2560FB5C289} for my code.

I am able to retrieve the PID from the PEVENT_RECORD structure with the below code.

```
VOID WINAPI ProcessEvent(PEVENT_RECORD pEvent)
{
    wprintf(L"ProcessEvent: processID: %d\n", pEvent->EventHeader.ProcessId);
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve the file name from PEVENT_RECORD->UserData field ? if so how do I it? Are there any examples?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/blob/main/src/TraceEvent/Parsers/kerneltraceeventparser.man.xml. There are FileName events emitted which contain FileObject ptr and the actual file name. The Create/Read... events do not contain the filename but the FileObject ptr value. You need to do the mapping on your own on the fly.